# Asp Core 2.0 VS 2017 Dependencies no lib created in wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need help with asp core 2.0 vs2017.
So i have added in npm and bower configuration file:

```
"Dependencies": {
    "jQuery": "3.3.1"
  }
```

and nothing was created in the wwwroot, it should create Lib and files inside but it didn't created, I can see the jQuery in the Dependencies folder.

Comment: please see this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I have created the bower file by my self, there is now bower configuration any more, so i don't have  .bowerrc file